# Conjunction reduction

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> It is common for a native American who has never driven a car to move to another part of the country and **have** to learn to do it.

My guess is that the sentence is wrong because in this part: *"have to learn to do it"*, *"have"* must agree with the subject, i.e. *"a native American"*, which is singular. Hence, it should be *"has to learn to do it"*.

Comment: The term "native American" should probably be changed to "American".  The meaning of the sentence does not depend on whether the person was born in the United States.  When spoken, "native American" sounds like "Native American", which is a politically correct term for "American Indian".  Changing "native American" to "Native American" reduces the number of people being discussed by a factor of 10 or 100.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is correct as written. "Have" is an infinitive in this case.

We can reduce the sentence like this:

> It is common for an American **to have** to learn this.

In the full sentence, "and" makes the "to" before "move" apply to "have" also.

You could also write "...and **to** have to learn..."